# dynamicmvc.com - render dropdown with model definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamicmvc

In one of the project (which I am updating) Dynamic MVC (http://www.dynamicmvc.com) has been used. I have to make one change it in one of the data capturing screen.

[Serializable]
[DynamicEntity]

```
public class DynamicTextField : TextField
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

   [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Domain I want to render as dropdown (US/EU/IN etc.)
    public string Domain { get; set; }**
}
```

With above definition is will render as textbox. Any way to render it as dropdown?

Comment: Having never used this before I can't answer with confidence - but I would suspect that all `string`s will be text boxes. Make `Domain` an enum or a class.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I can create a class as below:  
public class Domain
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
    }
 
 Then How do I make changes in DynamicModel? I tried few things but not working